# set x-axis display range

Tags: r, ggplot2

The example data:

```
nltt <- structure(list(time = c(0, 1.02579504946471, 1.66430039972234, 
    1.67435173974229, 1.82009140034063, 1.95574135900067, 2.06963147976273, 
    2.64869249896209, 3.10438864450297, 0, 0.56927280073675, 1.94864234867127, 
    3.40490224199942, 0, 0.444318793403606, 1.34697160089298, 5.86547288923207, 
    0, 1.10824151737219, 1.77801220982399, 1.82246583876729, 2.18034182214015, 
    2.33051663760657, 3.01615794541527, 0, 0.101501512884473, 0.98261402255534, 
    1.04492141817475, 1.16554239437694, 1.25441082400256, 1.25777371029976, 
    1.62464049949719, 1.87253384965378, 1.91118229908154, 1.94105777022533, 
    2.17755553127212, 2.37899716574036, 2.85003451051712, 3.16711386665322
    ), num = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14), rep = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -39L), class = "data.frame")
```

The example code:

```
  ggplot2::ggplot(nltt, aes(time, num, group = as.factor(rep), color = as.factor(rep))) + 
    ggplot2::geom_line() + ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3)) +
    ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none") + ggplot2::xlab("age")
```

The example plot:
[image]

I would like each line in the plot to stop precisely at `x = 3`, but adding `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3))` does not achieve my goal because the lines continues in the right padding area. How can I limit the lines in the range of `[0, 3]` without truncating my raw data?

Comment: Can you turn the values to `NA` for `time > 3` ? `nltt <- transform(nltt, time = replace(time, time > 3, NA))`

Comment: @RonakShah This equals to `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)` which will truncate the lines, so that they can't reach `x = 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Up front**: two answers, the first removes the margins and requires no change to the data; the second preserves the margins, which requires one to modify the data in-place.

---

### Remove the margin(s)

The default behavior is to `expand` the margins a little. While there is the `ggplot2::expansion` to control the `mult`iplicative and `add`itive components of the expansion, it can only be used in `scale_continuous` which, as you know, will result in loss (`NA`) of out-of-bound points.

If you can accept losing the boundary on the left as well, though, you can add `expand=FALSE` to your `coord_cartesian` and get your desired results:

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(nltt, aes(time, num, group = as.factor(rep), color = as.factor(rep))) + 
  ggplot2::geom_line() +
  ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3), expand = FALSE) +
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggplot2::xlab("age")
```

[image: ggplot with boundary expansion disabled]

If you want to retain the left margin, though, you can force it by adjusting the `xlim=`, realizing that the default is around `expansion(mult=0.05, add=0)`:

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(nltt, aes(time, num, group = as.factor(rep), color = as.factor(rep))) + 
  ggplot2::geom_line() +
  ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.15, 3), expand = FALSE) +
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggplot2::xlab("age")
```

[image: ggplot with boundary expansion disabled on the right and manually added on the left]

---

### Interpolate and truncate, external to `ggplot`

`ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(..., oob=)` supports several mechanisms for dealing with out-of-bounds data, including:

- the default `censor` (replaces with `NA`), which doesn't work since we don't have data *at* `time=3`
- `scales::squish` that will take (for example) `x=4` and squish it back to `x=3`; the unfortunate side-effect of this is that it is univariate (it does not attempt to change the corresponding `y=` value), so the slopes of the squished line segments will be steeper, and (in my mind at least) this corrupts the data and vis;
- a user-defined function that is passed the values and the associated limits; unfortunately, it is also univariate, so we're stuck with the same data/vis slope-corruption as the previous bullet.

This brings me to the suggestion to interpolate the data yourself before passing to `ggplot`. I'll demo with `dplyr` but it can be done easily with base R or other dialects as well.

```r
library(dplyr)

group_by(nltt, rep) %>%
  ## step 1: interpolate, returns *just* time=3 data, nothing more
  summarize(as.data.frame(setNames(approx(time, num, xout = 3), c("time", "num")))) %>%
  ## step 2: combine with the original data
  bind_rows(nltt) %>%
  ## step 3: remove data over 3
  dplyr::filter(time <= 3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, num, group = as.factor(rep), color = as.factor(rep))) + 
  ggplot2::geom_line() + ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3)) +
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggplot2::xlab("age")
```

[image: ggplot with data externally interpolated/truncated to time=3]

Comment: Is it possible to also keep the right margin?

Comment: I think it would be very easy that I slightly transform my raw data, but I am interested in whether we can do this within ggplot2

Comment: Oh, I see ... yes, and most of the ways to do that will (unfortunately) misshape the data (that is, one can have the values over 3 truncated to 3, but that will change the "slope" of the lines, since they won't similarly adjust the y-value). You'll need to interpolate and truncate the data external to `ggplot`.

Comment: See my edit for option number 2, external interpolation.